# How can one use Java 17 to write a CSV file in Shift_JIS encoding from a List of Strings, which includes Unicode characters such as ✓?

Tags: java-17

I am encountering an issue while attempting to write a CSV file using Java 17, which contains data including the "✓" character and other Japanese Unicode characters, in the Shift_JIS format.

How can I address this problem and successfully write a Shift_JIS formatted file that includes both Unicode and symbolic characters?

Comment: “I am encountering an issue” is not a useful problem description. Unless you consider “you have to find a solution” a satisfying answer.

Comment: There is an older identical question which should help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/39121352/150978